# How to indicate that a function expects a function as a parameter, or returns a function, via function annotations?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, annotations

You can use [function annotations](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) in python 3 to indicate the types of the parameters and return value, like so:

```
def myfunction(name: str, age: int) -> str:
    return name + str(age) #usefulfunction
```

But what if you were writing a function that expects a function as a parameter, or returns one?

I realize that you can write any valid expression in for the annotations, so I could write "function" as a string, but is that the best/only way of doing it? Is there nothing like the built-in types `int/float/str/list/dict` etc? I'm aware of `callable`, but I'm wondering if there's anything else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no style defined for annotations. Either use `callable`, `types.FunctionType` or a string.

PS: `callable` was not available in Python 3.0 and 3.1

Comment: I would suggest not using `callable` as it results in `<built-in function callable>` being returned for `__annotations__` rather than `<class 'function'>`

Answer (score 4):

Very interesting... I've never even heard of function annotations in Python 3.  The following code in the interpreter suggests you might use `function` in place of `str` and `int`.  Just my two cents.

```
>>> a = lambda x: x*2
>>> type(a)
<class 'function'>
```

Comment: Don't feel bad, neither had I until an hour ago. Learn something new every day....

Comment: type(a) where a is an int gives <class 'int'> where there are single quotes round int, just as around function in your example, but we don't use single quotes around int when using it as a type annotation in Python 3.

Comment: I tried what @SimonT is suggesting here as I thought that would be the correct solution too.  

What I found however is that this doesn't have the expected result when inspecting the annotations: `{'expected_function': <class 'dict'>}`.  Instead you get `{'expected_function': 'function'}` which makes it seem that the program is expecting you to pass the literal string 'function' into the method.

Comment: @eikonomega this is really strange now.